# Calculating a File's popularity by specific factors

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm currently developing a website where users can share, download, rate and favorite certain files. In order to display the most popular files, I've come up with an algorithm to calculate a score value for every file.

Right now, the score consists out of 50% like/dislike ratio and 50% the amount of downloads (I use an exponential function with an upper limit).
However, this algorithm does neither include the age of the file nor does it include the amount of favorites.

How would I include those factors to get the most popular files? Are there any best practices out there? I am currently developing in PHP, but Pseudocode is fine of course.

Thanks in advance,

CrushedPixel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that Reddit sorts out posts works really nicely. In case you don't know, Reddit, at first sorts by just upvotes. After a certain period of time (that I don't know) it adds weights to posts that allow newer posts to surface. I would suggest that you use this idea as a base for 6 different sorting methods that go into 3 groups. The groups would be favorites, downloads, and L/D ratio (each group would have sort by most/least making 6 sorting methods). Since each video would have all of these numbers stored in some sort of database, you could use the same algorithm for all of them. Just replace the variables with whatever sorting method has been chosen. As for a 4th, general purpose one, maybe take an average of a post's position on all 3 other sorting systems. For example, if a video is 1st on L/D, 2nd on favorites, and 2nd on downloads and it competes against a video that is 1st on favorites, 2nd in L/D and 3rd in downloads. The 1st posts average would be 1 and 1/3 while the 2nd posts average would be 2 (the lower the better). So, the first post would be 1st on the overall list and the 2nd post would be 2nd on the overall list.

Hope this helps!
Rad

Comment: Thumbs up for live example. Gonna have a look into it tomorrow.

Comment: This is a good resource on reddit's rating system: [link](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588)